# Frequency response of a differential amplifier

Tags: differential

I have to simulate the frequency response of the following differential amplifier:

[image]

Here are the simulation results:

[image]

The green graph represents (vin1-vin2)/vs and the red one represents (vout+ - vout-) / (vin2-vin1) (both of them are in dBs).

I have some doubts about the validity of these results. Qualitatively speaking, the way C1 is connected is supposed to provide a response of a high-pass filter but the results show otherwise.

What can be the reason for that? Is there something wrong with the simulation itself? Is the circuit above somehow flawed? The quiescent point of the two transistors is identical (confirmed in a DC analysis).

I just need some intuitive guidance on what is wrong with the simulation, there is no need to refer to the values of the elements present in the circuit.

Answer (score 3):

1. Plot Vin1 separately, the *difference* between the inputs will remain a constant voltage at low frequency when far below the GBW of the amplifier.
2. Extend the lower frequency range of the simulation and you will see the high-pass behavior. As it is, the corner frequency \$\propto\frac{1}{RB1\cdot C1}\$ is in the ballpark of 1 Hz.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! I had lowered the start frequency significantly and I could observe HP behavior.